# Elasticsearch unexpected result while searching with match_phrase_prefix on turkish characters

Tags: elasticsearch

There is an index which has one field that is the content about pdf or any other document includes turkish characters.

When i search some words in turkish characters if i wrote more word results comes more.

For  example:

```
          {
            "match_phrase_prefix": {
              "fieldOfContent": "istanbul ü"
            }
          }
```

result:

```
"hits" : {
"total" : {
  "value" : 9,
  "relation" : "eq"
}
```

second case:

```
          {
            "match_phrase_prefix": {
              "fieldOfContent": "istanbul üni"
            }
          }
```

result:

```
"hits" : {
"total" : {
  "value" : 11,
  "relation" : "eq"
}
```

i did not used any analyzer for turkish but i want to know what i am doing wrong.

note: results are coming like this: "İstanbul Üni...." so i mean elasticsearch capable with uppercase version of i in turkish.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about the exact "analyzer" and "tokenizer" that you have used for this particular "fieldofcontent" field, Its hard to explain this behaviour.
Some suggestions:

1. Run the _analyze API and check what your fieldofcontent gets analyzed into. For eg when I run the text you provided I get this output:

```
GET _analyze
{
  "analyzer" : "standard",
  "text" : "istanbul üni"
}
 
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "istanbul",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 8,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "üni",
      "start_offset" : 9,
      "end_offset" : 12,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 1
    }
  ] 
}
```

The "standard" analyzer is used by default if you didn't specify an analyzer. THe match-phrase-prefix query will use the same analyzer to split the search string before it runs the search. So if you simply took whatever was in your "fieldofcontent" ran an _analyze on it, you would probably have the answer to this behaviour.

HTH.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I analyzed it and i have found that i was not using standart analyzer, the field is using turkish analyzer. I am not an elasticsearch expert so this information makes not much sense to me.

Comment: Change it to the standard analyzer, and you will get the results you expect. Pls mark my answer as correct. Thank you

Comment: i dont want to change analyzer, so i solved the issue with splitting the sentence and searching with wildcard and adding to end '*' for every word.